# UWP store frame on navigation

Tags: uwp, navigation, frame

In my UWP app I want to use a frame for navigating between two(or more) pages. The content of a page is determined by the user by selecting from a list. When the selection of the list changes, the `frame.Navigate()` method gets called:

```
FruitsFrame.Navigate(typeof(ApplePage));
```

This works fine, but every time the mothod gets called a new instance is created thus discarding changes made to ApplePage.

My workaraound was to pass the `ApplePage` as parameter, but that felt quite wrong.
I could use

```
FruitsFrame.Content = applePage;
```

instead, but `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` won't get called. At the moment I rely on both events, beacause the start and stop task within the ApplePage.

So how can I use the page navigation properly? The only solution that comes to my mind is to build a wrapper class, that holds all information neccesary (including the tasks) which would be quite similar to a viewModel. Is this how frames were intended to use?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following Code:

```
>         public Page()
>         {
>             this.InitializeComponent();
>             this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
>         }
```

Comment: If I use this with multiple Apple Pages changes made to one page apply to all instances (Apple Pages)

Answer (score 0):

`Frame` is mostly intended to function as a holder for a navigation stack. As such it can hold the currently displayed page, the history of opened pages and their navigation parameters. In case the `NavigationCache` is enabled and `NavigationCacheMode` for individual pages is enabled, it can even keep the pages in the navigation stack in memory including the state of their controls.

In your case however it sounds like we are not talking about a "stack"-based navigation, but rather something like "tabs" - multiple pages of content that should stay in memory and should be restored. In this case you have two options.

The first is the one you already discovered - keeping the pages in memory and setting them as `Content` of a content control. It does not have to be a `Frame` per-se, but can instead be just a simple `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`. To make things even cleaner, you could then use `UserControls` instead of `Pages`, so that the navigation aspect of a page is clearly unavailable and you can't accidentally rely on the navigation events.

The second solution would be to actually use some kind of MVVM solution, which would allow you to keep in memory the associated `ViewModel`, which would contain the user-based state and would stay in memory, while the page and its UI would be destroyed. This is preferable, because UI-based controls do strain memory and simple data-based view model will be incomparably cheaper. In this case you would first navigate to the page and then check a view model locator for either a new or existing instance of the appropriate view model which you would set as the `DataContext` of your page. MvvmLight already offers a ViewModel locator out of the box, so it might be a good fit for your needs.